# UIScrollView with UITableView / UICollectionView zooming issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

**What i want to achieve :**
I want to creating scrolling list of images like a comic strip where i should be able to provide pinch and zoom. It can contain 100 images.

**What i have tried :**

1. UIScrollView -> UIView -> UIImageView : The problem in this approach is that i get the zooming effect but the time taken to create the strip is around 5 sec and the memory consumption of the app becomes high.
2. UIScrollView -> UIView -> UITableView -> UITableViewCell -> UIImageView : This resolves loading issue , memory issue . But the problem is with Zooming . I cannot achieve the same effect of Zooming on UITableView. I added the pinch gesture on the UITableView it zooms and scrolls vertically but horizontal effect is not achieved.
3. UICollectionView -> UIImageView : This also resolves loading issue , memory issue but has same problem with zooming as it zooms a particular cell but after zooming to certain effect the cell disappears . And its also not uniformly applied to all UICollectionViewCells.

Any reference or code or idea's really appreciated.

Comment: Just an idea: I wouldl try to use the first option but using images with poor quality and replace this images  when the scrolls gets closer

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the problem with option 1 is that you are loading all 100 images at once when the view loads.
If that is the case you could reduce the number of images you keep loaded in memory to a small amount.
For example just load 5, the image being viewed, 2 before it in the list and the 2 that come after it. When the user views the next image in either direction update the loaded images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing an application that it likes what she said.

```html
//初始化ScrollView
        let scrollView = PalyView.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2
        scrollView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        
        
        //初始化_collectionView
        _collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height * 5), collectionViewLayout: _layout)
        _collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        _collectionView?.delegate = self
        _collectionView?.dataSource = self
        _collectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        _collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 6, 0)
        _collectionView?.register(WaterCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        scrollView.addSubview(_collectionView!)
```